# Reference Request: Cech cohomology of complexes on an arbitrary site

Tags: simplicial-complexes, cech-cohomology, sites

I am looking for a reference which is equivalent to this stacks project page [1], except formulated in the generality of an arbitrary site. I checked the "Cohomology on Sites" section of the stacks project and couldn't find it there. I also couldn't find it in EGA or SGA, but my knowledge of these references is far from perfect.

1. https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/01FP

Comment: Have looked at SGA4 exposé V and Vbis? That's pretty general.

Comment: I have, but it seems to me that only the Cech cohomology of a single sheaf is considered in SGA4 exposé V and Vbis, and not a complex of such. But I could be wrong.